# android add text line at the beginning of .txt file

Tags: java, android

I have this code

```
 File gpxfile = new File(root, "mesaje.txt");

            BufferedWriter bW;

            bW = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(gpxfile, true));
            bW.write(format + " " + message + "\n-----------------------\n");
            bW.newLine();
            bW.flush();
            bW.close();
```

It writes a .txt file adding text after the last line. I would like to add text on the first line, so that it will appear as the lastest information. How can i do that? Thanks!

Comment: Get the contents, prepend your new line, rewrite the file.

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR it writes the text bellow the other lines. I want to write it on top of other lines

Answer (score 0):

Read the file, store it into a string. Then simply rewrite the file by adding your new text and then the string saved from previous file.
Plenty of examples on here for reading text files